# Custom theme in my application

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm tring to create custom theme from my application and i have the ListView of my Navigation Drawer that have a different color depending of if it's activated or not. I have this selector in drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="?myFirstColor"/>
    <item android:color="?mySecondColor"/>

</selector>
```

in /values/attrs.xml i've

```
<resources>   
    <attr name="myFirstColor" format="reference|color"/>
    <attr name="mySecondColor" format="reference|color"/> 
</resources>
```

In style.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="myFirstColor">@color/red_holo</item>
    <item name="mySecondColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

But when i run the application the color are not red_holo and white. Why?

The xml for the navdrawer adapter is this

```
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/mySelector">
```

i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You should try Hex Color Codes,

try #ff0055 instead of red_holo.

Comment: The problem is in the selector. If i put your hex instead of ?miFirstColor works. But with ?miFirstColor i obtain a color that i've never defined into my source code. How can i solve?